# Send data(command) from raspberry pi 3 to Smart home devices

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, bluez

I want to send data(command) from raspberry pi 3 to smart home device(smart AC/FAN) via **Bluetooth** to control smart home devices(on/off).

For example - If i say to Raspberry pi (using command line) to turn off Kitchen fan. Then command will send to kitchen fan and it should be turn off.

1. Which Bluetooth Protocol is more secure and easy to implement in this scenario ?
    (RFCOMM/TCP/L2CAP/SMP)
2. Which Programming Language is more suitable with those Bluetooth protocols ?
3. Is there any Universal Command to ON/OFF every smart devices or Should i have to write different commands for different devices ? 
    (If possible - give some reference links).

Thanks in Advance for your Suggestions and Helps. Actually, I am software Engineer and beginner in Communication Part, So if you can't understand Actual Task/Situation(it's my bad), then please let me know. I explain a Task in more detail so hopefully you understand well.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer. TCP is not a Bluetooth protocol and all other protocols you mentioned are at different layer in bluetooth protocol stack. You can start with understanding RFCOMM. RPI3 runs bluez. Read about bluez.

Comment: Hallo @Ravi first of all thanks for your suggestions. Here TCP mean, Telephony control protocol (TCP) not Transmission Control Protocol.

Comment: Secondly I am successfully Connected via Bluetooth to Smart Home Devices, But those Bluetooth Protocols i need to use transfer data(commands)  between them. How should i create new Command and send over Bluetooth to smart devices. Any reference link would be helpful. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Firstly, know about the Bluetooth profile which your Bluetooth Smart Home Device implemented. sdptool command can help you with this. If it is using any Bluetooth defined profile then read about the protocol. If not, you need to know your device messaging protocol.

Comment: http://www.bluez.org/profiles/ this link has the list of profiles that linux bluetooth stack has implemented.

Comment: @Ravi Thanks for your suggestion. I think you are right, first off all need to know about which Bluetooth Protocol used by my Smart Device. Do you have any links for **control command for Smart Device.**  That would be great help.